# What size screws were used in the Amiga desktop cases?

Tags: amiga, restoration, case, screw

On the Amiga 500, 500+, 600, and 1200, what size screws were used to hold the chassis together? Is it the same size screw for all, different screws per machine, different screws front and rear, or were all the holes designed to work with more than one size screw depending on what the factory happened to have in stock?

Comment: On the Amiga, if it was not Phillips, it was either Allen Key, or Torx.

Answer (score 9):

There is very little information online about this, so I have scraped around and put this together:

The screws on the Amiga 500 and 500+ were often Phillips (requiring a #2 Phillips head screwdriver<sup>[[1]](//web.archive.org/http://amiga.resource.cx/manual/AdIDE2.pdf)</sup>), but hex-socket (Allen key) screws were also used<sup>[[4]](//web.archive.org/web/20160517204022/http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Amiga-500-500plus-Hex-type-case-fixing-kit-Screws-set-of-10-screws-/121962809701)</sup>.

[trall](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/75/traal) measured the external case screws on an A500 case that appear to be original. They are Torx T9, the rear three (3) are 9.0mm long at the shank and 13 threads/inch. The front three (3) are 7.5mm long, and two (2) of those are 13 threads/inch and one (1) is 29 threads/inch.

Most of the screws for the 600 and 1200 are six millimetres long<sup>[[2]](//web.archive.org/web/20160328054249/http://amigakit.leamancomputing.com/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=992)</sup> and appear to be Phillips screws<sup>[[3]](//web.archive.org/web/20160422061416/http://amigakit.leamancomputing.com/catalog/images/case-screws.jpg)</sup> as well, however there are shorter screws for the lower front edge<sup>[[5]](//web.archive.org/web/20160517205017/http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Commodore-Amiga-600-and-1200-case-screws-6-Screw-Set-A600-A1200-/182115335561)</sup> on these machines.

Comment: A good answer to any question about screw sizes would include the thread pitch and shank size, for example [here](https://www.boltdepot.com/Machine_screws_Phillips_pan_head_Stainless_steel_18-8.aspx).  You can't go buy the correct screw without this information.

Comment: Note to go and buy a screw you also need the diameter... Also note that 13 TPI works out to ~0.5mm pitch in metric. My guess would be those are standard M3 metric screws.

Comment: After all, the Amiga was produced in times when the US where still trying to go metric :)

Comment: @tofro 13 threads per inch is 0.5mm???? I don't think so. Work it out.... 25.4 / 13 = 1.95mm. Definitely NOT 13 TPI ! With a 0.5mm pitch it would be equivalent to ~50TPI, but that simply doesn't exist. Yes of course the fine pitch threads are metric M3.
Here is a standard thread chart for reference... https://mdmetric.com/tech/tict.htm